# Abigen reuses nonce when deploying a contract

Tags: solc, abigen

We have a contract called C1 that uses another contract called RoleLib:

```
    using RoleLib for uint8;
```

We compile it with solc:

solc --combined-json abi,bin ./solidity/c1/C1.sol -o deploy/c1 --base-path .

and then generate the deployer with abigen:

```
abigen --combined-json=./deploy/c1/combined.json --pkg=c1 --out=deploy/c1/C1.go
```

which produces the following code, which obviously reuses the nonce in auth:

```
func DeployC1(auth *bind.TransactOpts, backend bind.ContractBackend) (common.Address, *types.Transaction, *C1, error) {
parsed, err := C1MetaData.GetAbi()
if err != nil {
    return common.Address{}, nil, nil, err
}
if parsed == nil {
    return common.Address{}, nil, nil, errors.New("GetABI returned nil")
}

roleLibAddr, _, _, _ := DeployRoleLib(auth, backend)
C1Bin = strings.ReplaceAll(C1Bin, "__$3897a2e8704322a01bd00e453622dcaf8a$__", roleLibAddr.String()[2:])

address, tx, contract, err := bind.DeployContract(auth, *parsed, common.FromHex(C1Bin), backend)
if err != nil {
    return common.Address{}, nil, nil, err
}
return address, tx, &C1{C1Caller: C1Caller{contract: contract}, C1Transactor: C1Transactor{contract: contract}, C1Filterer: C1Filterer{contract: contract}}, nil
```

}

so when deploying we get:

```
the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 4 tx has nonce of: 3
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found out that leaving out the nonce in auth, it gets autoincremented, so the transactions go through.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Get the current nonce for the sender's address using:

```
    nonce, err := backend.PendingNonceAt(auth.From)
if err != nil {
    return common.Address{}, nil, nil, err
}
```

Increment the nonce by 1 to ensure it's higher than the previous transaction:

```
auth.Nonce = big.NewInt(int64(nonce + 1))
```

Now

```
    address, tx, contract, err := DeployC1(auth, backend)
if err != nil {
    return common.Address{}, nil, nil, err
}
```

By doing this, you'll make sure that the transaction you're sending has the correct nonce and won't conflict with previous transactions from the same address.

Comment: Thanks Mehran, that works, but the above code is autogenerated so I can't modify it in an automated workflow. Ideally, abigen should do it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it seems you should develop a custom script or tool that acts as a wrapper around it.